# Eliminar "\t" o "\n" de un String en Java

Tags: java

Necesito implementar un método el que al momento de ingresar el siguiente String salga así

```
Entrada: "[WARNING]:   \tTimezone not set  \r\n"

Salida: [Timezone not set]
```

o también:

```
Entrada: "[ERROR]: \t Corrupt disk\t \t \r\n"

Salida: "[Corrupt disk] (error)"
```

No sé de que manera puedo eliminar esos espacios espaciales como "\t" "\r" "\n"

```
    //Entra: "[WARNING]:   \tTimezone not set  \r\n"
    //Debería salir: "Timezone not set"
     public static String message(String logLine) {
        String[] logLineSeparated = logLine.split(": ");
        return logLineSeparated[1];
    }

    //Entra: "[INFO]: Timezone changed"
    //Sale: "info"
   public static String logLevel(String logLine) {
        String[] listBeforeBeSeparated = logLine.split("]: ");
        StringBuilder logLevel = new StringBuilder(listBeforeBeSeparated[0]);
        logLevel.deleteCharAt(0);
        String result = String.valueOf(logLevel);
        return result.toLowerCase();
    }

    //Entrada: "[ERROR]: \t Corrupt disk\t \t \r\n"
    //Debería salir: "Corrupt disk (error)"
    
 public static String reformat(String logLine) {
        String message = message(logLine);
        String logLevel = logLevel(logLine);
        return message +" ("+logLevel+")";
    }
```

Todos los métodos funcionan correctamente pero no superan los casos de prueba en caso de tener estos caracteres especiales que por cierto no sé el nombre

Comment: podrías hacer uso de **replaceAll** System.out.println(message(logLine.replaceAll("\\r|\\n|\\t","")));

Answer (score 2):

Realiza dos cambios en tu código:

1. Elimina todos los espacios al inicio y al final y los caracteres especiales usando:

```java
logLine = logLine.strip().replaceAll("(\\r|\\n|\\t)", "");
```

2. Realiza el split teniendo en cuenta que pueden haber más de un espacio en blanco:

```java
String[] listBeforeBeSeparated = logLine.split("]:\\s+");
```

Tus métodos quedarían:

```java
    public static String message(String logLine) {
        String[] logLineSeparated = logLine.split(":\\s+");
        return logLineSeparated[1];
    }

    //Entra: "[INFO]: Timezone changed"
    //Sale: "info"
    public static String logLevel(String logLine) {
        String[] listBeforeBeSeparated = logLine.split("]:\\s+");
        StringBuilder logLevel = new StringBuilder(listBeforeBeSeparated[0]);
        logLevel.deleteCharAt(0);
        String result = String.valueOf(logLevel);
        return result.toLowerCase();
    }

    //Entrada: "[ERROR]: \t Corrupt disk\t \t \r\n"
    //Debería salir: "Corrupt disk (error)"
    public static String reformat(String logLine) {
        logLine = logLine.strip().replaceAll("(\\r|\\n|\\t)", "");
        String message = message(logLine);
        String logLevel = logLevel(logLine);
        return message +" ("+logLevel+")";
    }
```

He realizado la siguiente prueba con lo que adjuntas y la ha pasado sin problemas:

```java
    @Test
    void reformatShouldReformatString() {
        String logLine1 = "[ERROR]: \t Corrupt disk\t \t \r\n";
        String logLine2 = "[WARNING]:   \tTimezone not set  \r\n";
        assertEquals("Corrupt disk (error)", LogUtils.reformat(logLine1));
        assertEquals("Timezone not set (warning)", LogUtils.reformat(logLine2));
    }
```